# Print 5 elements of a list per line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I have a list and I need to print 5 elements per line to get:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

I tried everything but I'm stuck, help!

Comment: _I tried everything but.._ post your efforts

Comment: **@Joaquin**, you can use `%` operator to check the index of 5th, 10th, 15th,...items and based on that you can go to new line otherwise continue printing items in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

**@Joaquin**, try below code:

> http://rextester.com/BLN7722

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for index, item in enumerate(l):
    if (index + 1) % 5 == 0:
        print(item)
    else:
        print(item, end=" ")

"""
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
"""
```